# Sound from gear box

Tags: chevrolet, noise, equinox

I had to brake hard bcuz of another car and that evening my wife drove to the store and she noticed the the brake assist was on and parking brake was on not sure if drive with it on or not as she had parked already. But now I hear a sound like pushing one side of a soda can from where my gear shifter is when I'm parked and pressing the brakes.. that is what I need info is that sound but it seems that al other brake systems are ok... I'm wondering if my gear box moved or shifted during the hard stop

2019 Chevrolet Equinox

Comment: My advice is to get a qualified mechanic to look at this ASAP.  It sounds very abnormal and I'd be concerned that there is some serious braking (i.e. SAFETY) issue in play now.

Comment: Sounds like good advice I wouldn't want to guess, have you not got breakdown cover, maybe came with your insurance they might be able to tell you

Comment: Sounds like good advice I wouldn't want to guess, have you not got breakdown coverage, maybe came with your insurance they might be able to tell you. Comment by new user Danny Mayhew